# How to order mysql query results by random() and by another field?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, random, sql-order-by

I have the following query which sorts results randomly:

```
$sql = "SELECT *, `active` FROM `profiles` WHERE CONCAT(',' , pfCategory , ',') LIKE '%$category%' AND `active`='1' ORDER BY RAND()";
```

I would like to add a boolean field in `profiles` table so the random results with value 1 will appear on top of those with value 0 in the random list. Is that possible? Thanks

Comment: Yes why don't you try out yourself first and tell us what issue you face after trying that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using below query:

```
$sql = "SELECT *, `active` FROM `profiles` WHERE CONCAT(',' , pfCategory , ',') LIKE '%$category%' AND `active`='1' ORDER BY boolean_field_name DESC, RAND()";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$sql = "SELECT *, `active` FROM `profiles` WHERE CONCAT(',' , pfCategory , ',') LIKE '%$category%' AND `active`='1' ORDER BY active, RAND()";
```

if Active is field for sorting.

Best regards,
Nebojsa

Answer (score 0):

you can use a case here

```
 order by case when `active`='1' then 0
               else rand() end
```